# postfix evaluation using stack

Tags: c++, file, stack, postfix-notation

i'am trying to read postfix expression from txt file and evaluate it
 the input is 10 5 * ,the output should be 50, but it reads only 10 and 5,
he can't read the operators neither there ascii code , any help?
 here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 40
int stack[SIZE];
int top=-1;

void push(int n)
{
    if(top==SIZE-1)
    {
        printf("Stack is full\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        top=top+1;
        stack[top]=n;
        printf("Pushed element is %d\n",n);
        system("pause");
    }
}

int pop()
{
    int n;
    if(top==-1)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        n=stack[top];
        top=top-1;

        return(n);
    }
}

int main() 
{

    int str[50],ch;

    int i=0;
    int n,op1,op2;

    ifstream inFile;
    ch=str[i];

    inFile.open("D:\\me.txt");
    if (!inFile) 
    {
        printf( "Unable to open file");
        system("pause");
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    while (inFile >> ch) 
    {
        if(ch=='+' || ch=='-' || ch=='*' || ch=='/' || ch=='%' || ch=='^' )
        {

            op1=pop();
            op2=pop();
            if (op1<op2)
            {
                n=op1;
                op1=op2;
                op2=n;
            }
            if(ch=='+')
                n=op1+op2;
            else if(ch=='-')
                n=op1-op2;
            else if(ch=='*')
                n=op1*op2;
            else if(ch=='/')
                n=op1/op2;
            else if(ch=='%')
                n=op1%op2;
            else if(ch=='^')
                n=op1^op2;
            else
            {
                printf("The operator is not identified\n");
                system("pause");
                exit(0);
            }

            printf("n=%d\n",n);
            system("pause");
            push(n);


        }
        else
        {
            n=ch;
            push(n);
        }
        ch=str[++i];
    }
    inFile.close();
    printf("The value of the arithmetic expression is=%d\n",pop());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ch` is an `int` so `inFile >> ch` will only read nummbers - the `'*'` character is ignored.

Also, you have a `str[]` array which is uninitialized that you periodically read out of to assign to `ch` (then you ignore whatever just got written into `ch`).  You need to get rid of `str[]` or complete the thought that made you put it there in the first place...